MPI works with 4 processor but fails with more, problem with decomposition? Send/Recv? 2d Heat diffusion
I have to simulate 2D plate heat diffusion. Everything works fine with 4 tasks, but it doesn't when using N*4 tasks. I suspect the problem is in the logic of communications between the upper and lower "ghost rows."
int t=0;
        for (t = 0; t < integration_time; t++)
        {
            
            
            if (taskid == 1)
            {
                neighbor_down = taskid + 1;
                neighbor_up = taskid - 1;
                MPI_Send(&temp[offset+chunksize-1][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_down, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Send(&temp[offset][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_up, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Recv(&temp[offset+chunksize][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_down, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                MPI_Recv(&temp[offset-1][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_up, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                /* Send timestep to master */
                
            }
            if (taskid == numtasks - 1)
            {
                neighbor_up = taskid - 1;
                MPI_Send(&temp[offset][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_up, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Recv(&temp[offset-1][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_up, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            }
            
            
            if (taskid % 2 == 0 && taskid != 1 && taskid != numtasks - 1)
                {
                    neighbor_up = taskid - 1;
                    neighbor_down = taskid + 1;
                    
                    MPI_Recv(&temp[offset-1][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_up, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                    MPI_Recv(&temp[offset+chunksize][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_down, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                    MPI_Send(&temp[offset][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_up, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                    MPI_Send(&temp[offset+chunksize-1][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_down, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                }
            if (taskid % 2 != 0 && taskid != 1 && taskid != numtasks - 1)
                {
                    neighbor_up = taskid - 1;
                    neighbor_down = taskid + 1;
                    
                    MPI_Send(&temp[offset][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_up, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                    MPI_Send(&temp[offset+chunksize-1][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_down, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                    MPI_Recv(&temp[offset-1][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_up, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                    MPI_Recv(&temp[offset+chunksize][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_down, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                }

When running with more than 4 tasks, it stucks in entering the main loop of master process.
Someone has some idea?
I'm sorry for the poor code optimization, but i'm new to C and parallel programming!
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <math.h>

#define ROWS 64
#define COLUMNS 64
#define MASTER 0
#define CONTROL_TEMP 10000000
#define integration_time 1000

void inidat(int nx, int ny, float *u);
void prtdat(int nx, int ny, float *u, char *fnam);
void diffuse(int nx, int ny, float *t_old, float *t_new, float cx, float cy);

float temp[ROWS][COLUMNS];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float cy, cx;
    cy=0.2;
    cx=0.2;
    int numtasks, taskid, rc, dest, offset, i, j, tag1, tag2, source, chunksize;
    MPI_Status status;
    int ghost_up, ghost_down;
    float* t_new;
    float* t_old;
    int ix, iy;
    int nx, ny;
    ny = ROWS;
    nx = COLUMNS;

    /***** Initializations *****/
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
    if (numtasks % 4 != 0)
    {
        printf("Quitting. Number of MPI tasks must be divisible by 4.\n");
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rc);
        exit(0);
    }

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &taskid);
    //printf("MPI task %d has started...\n", taskid);
    chunksize = (ROWS / numtasks);
    tag1 = 1;
    tag2 = 2;

    /***** Master task only ******/
    if (taskid == MASTER)
    {                                   
        for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) /* Initialize the array */
        {
            for (j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
            {
                temp[i][j] = 0;
            }

        }
        /* Create boundary condition with temperature at CONTROL_TEMP at the center of the domain */
        temp[ROWS/2][COLUMNS/2] = CONTROL_TEMP;


        
        prtdat(ROWS, COLUMNS, &temp[0][0], "initial.dat");

        /* Subdivide the domain into N_TASKS horizontal stripes that we will send to each WORKER */
        
        chunksize = ROWS/numtasks;
        offset = chunksize;
        for (dest = 1; dest < numtasks; dest++)
        {
            MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&temp[offset][0], chunksize*COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, dest, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            offset = offset + chunksize;
        }
        offset = 0;
        

        /* Exchange data with task 1, receive and send timestep */
        int neighbor_down, neighbor_up;
        neighbor_down = taskid + 1;
        int t = 0;
        printf("Master entering loop\n");
        char filename[40];
        for (t = 0; t < integration_time; t++)
        {
            for (j = 1; j < offset+chunksize; j++)
            {
                for (i = 1; i < COLUMNS-1; i++)
                {
                    temp[j][i] = temp[j][i]+cx*(temp[j+1][i]+temp[j-1][i]-2.0*temp[j][i])+cy*(temp[j][i+1]+temp[j][i-1]-2.0*temp[j][i]);
                    
                }
                
            }
            
            
            
            
            MPI_Send(&temp[chunksize-1][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, 1, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Recv(&temp[chunksize][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, 1, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            
            for (i = 1; i < numtasks; i++)
            {
                source = i;
                MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                MPI_Recv(&temp[offset][0], chunksize*COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, source, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            }

            // Create a filename with the timestep name
            
            sprintf(filename, "data/final_%d", t);

            prtdat(ROWS, COLUMNS, &temp[0][0], filename);
            
        }
       
    }

    

    /***** Non-master tasks only *****/
    if (taskid > MASTER)
    {
        /* Receive temp[j][i] from master */
        source = MASTER;
        
        MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&temp[offset][0], chunksize*COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, source, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        
       /* Creates the ghost zone for each task. Basically the upper and bottom row comunicates, after each timestep, 
          the temperature to the upper an lower task */

        
        int neighbor_down, neighbor_up;

        /* Check if taskid = first or last [first = 1, last = numtasks - 1] */
        


   
        int t=0;
        for (t = 0; t < integration_time; t++)
        {
            
            
            if (taskid == 1)
            {
                neighbor_down = taskid + 1;
                neighbor_up = taskid - 1;
                MPI_Send(&temp[offset+chunksize-1][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_down, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Send(&temp[offset][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_up, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Recv(&temp[offset+chunksize][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_down, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                MPI_Recv(&temp[offset-1][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_up, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                /* Send timestep to master */
                
            }
            if (taskid == numtasks - 1)
            {
                neighbor_up = taskid - 1;
                MPI_Send(&temp[offset][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_up, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Recv(&temp[offset-1][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_up, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            }
            
            
            if (taskid % 2 == 0 && taskid != 1 && taskid != numtasks - 1)
                {
                    neighbor_up = taskid - 1;
                    neighbor_down = taskid + 1;
                    
                    MPI_Recv(&temp[offset-1][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_up, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                    MPI_Recv(&temp[offset+chunksize][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_down, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                    MPI_Send(&temp[offset][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_up, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                    MPI_Send(&temp[offset+chunksize-1][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_down, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                }
            if (taskid % 2 != 0 && taskid != 1 && taskid != numtasks - 1)
                {
                    neighbor_up = taskid - 1;
                    neighbor_down = taskid + 1;
                    
                    MPI_Send(&temp[offset][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_up, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                    MPI_Send(&temp[offset+chunksize-1][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_down, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                    MPI_Recv(&temp[offset-1][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_up, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                    MPI_Recv(&temp[offset+chunksize][0], COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, neighbor_down, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                }
                
                

            
            for (j = offset; j < offset+chunksize; j++)
                {
                    for (i = 1; i < COLUMNS-1; i++)
                    {
                        temp[j][i] = temp[j][i]+cx*(temp[j+1][i]+temp[j-1][i]-2.0*temp[j][i])+cy*(temp[j][i+1]+temp[j][i-1]-2.0*temp[j][i]);
                    }
                }/* Send the ghost zone to the upper and bottom task */
            
            MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&temp[offset][0], chunksize*COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, MASTER, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

            //send the data back to the master
            

        
        
            
            
        }
        printf("Task %d finished updating temperature\n", taskid);
        // send the data back to the master
        MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&temp[offset][0], chunksize*COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, MASTER, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    }
        
    

    
    // master receives the data from the workers
    if(taskid == MASTER)
    {
        for (i = 1; i < numtasks; i++)
        {
            source = i;
            MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            MPI_Recv(&temp[offset][0], chunksize*COLUMNS, MPI_FLOAT, source, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        }
        printf("Master received FINAL data from workers\n");
       
        prtdat(ROWS, COLUMNS, &temp[0][0], "final.dat");
 
    }

    // Print the final data to file
    
    MPI_Finalize();






    

    return 0;
}
/* Function to update the temperature at each step */
void diffuse(int nx, int ny, float *t_old, float *t_new, float cx, float cy)
{
    int ix, iy;
    
    for (iy=1; iy < ny-1; iy++){
        for(ix=1; ix < nx-1; iy++){
            *(t_new+ix*ny+iy) = *(t_old+ix*ny+iy) + cx * (*(t_old+(ix+1)*ny+iy) + *(t_old+(ix-1)*ny+iy) - 2.0 * *(t_old+ix*ny+iy)) + cy * *(t_old+ix*ny+iy+1) + *(t_old+ix*ny+iy-1) - 2.0* *(t_old+ix*ny+iy);
        }
    }

    for (iy=1; iy < ny-1; iy++){
        for(ix=1; ix <nx-1; ix++){
            *(t_old+ix*ny+iy) = *(t_new+ix*ny+iy);
        }
    }


}


void prtdat(int nx, int ny, float *u1, char *fnam)
{
   int ix, iy;
   FILE *fp;

   fp = fopen(fnam, "w");
   for (ix = 0; ix <= nx-1; ix++) {
      for (iy = 0; iy <= ny-1; iy++) {
        fprintf(fp, "%8.3f", *(u1+ix*ny+iy));
        if (iy != ny-1) {
           fprintf(fp, " ");
           }
       else {
          fprintf(fp, "\n");
          }
       }
    }
   fclose(fp);
   printf(" %s\n",fnam);
}

void prntfile(int nx, int ny, float *u1, char *fnam)
{
   int ix, iy;
   FILE *fp;

   fp = fopen(fnam, "w");
   for (ix = 0; ix <= nx-1; ix++) {
      for (iy = 0; iy <= ny-1; iy++) {
        fprintf(fp, "%8.3f", *(u1+ix*ny+iy));
        if (iy != ny-1) {
           fprintf(fp, " ");
           }
       else {
          fprintf(fp, "\n");
          }
       }
    }
   fclose(fp);
   printf(" %s\n",fnam);
}

I've tried changing the send recv order but things get worse.

master exchange MPI_FLOAT before MPI_INT but task 1 does it the other way around.

These patterns are very deadlock prone, so you should use neighbourhood collectives if they are a fit. Otherwise, try using MPI_Isend(), MPI_Irecv() and a single MPI_Waitall().
